# Can I get a bound of the 2-norm of a sum of matrices times vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices, matrix-norms

I am seeking for help about whether the following inequality is true:

I have k rank-one real matrices in $R^{d\times d}$, $x_1x_1^T, x_2x_2^T,...,x_kx_k^T$, where each $x_i$ is a vector in $R^d$ and $||x_i||_2\leq 1$, and I have k real vectors $y_1,y_2,...,y_k$ in $R^d$ and $||y_i||_2\leq c$ for each i. Is the following inequality true?

$||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2$?

I have tried to prove it but so far I have not found a way to do that.

I can get the following:
$||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}||x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq \sum_{i=1}^{k}||x_ix_i^T||_2||y_i||_2\leq c\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{max}(x_ix_i^T)\leq ck$. But I want to prove $||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2$.

At first I wanted to prove $||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq c||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2$, but I found a counter-example by taking $x_1x_1^T=\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}$， $x_2x_2^T=\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix}$, and $y_1=[1, 0]$, $y_2=[0,1]$, by this, $c=1$, LHS=$\sqrt{2}$, so I guess there should be a $\sqrt{d}$ in the RHS. I have not found a counter-example for $||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2$. Could anyone please help prove it right or wrong?

Exodd has helped me with the question below. I want to further prove the following result:
$||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}$.

Is this provable? Previously I thought if the first inequality is true, then this one will directly follows, but I made a mistake, below is what I tried:

$||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\leq ||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}||_2 ||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i||_2\\\leq c\sqrt{d}||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}||_2 ||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2\leq c\sqrt{d}$.

But I found that I can not get $||(\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T+\lambda I)^{-1}||_2 ||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2  \leq 1$. Then, can we prove the inequality holds?

Million thanks!

Comment: could you report what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to prove this but I don't know how to do that. And I can not find a counter-example.

Comment: please, add something that shows you have worked on the problem, otherwise we cannot answer by rules of the website

Comment: OK, thanks very much for your comment and reminder. I have tried to prove this but failed, I will add something that I have tried. I would appreciate it a lot if you would like to help me prove this.

Comment: Dear Exodd, I have added some comments, could you please kindly help me with it? Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, call $A$ the $d\times k$ matrix that has $x_i$ as columns, and $z$ a length $k$ vector whose entries are $x_i^Ty_i$.

$$
\|\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^Ty_i\|_2^2 = \|Az\|_2^2 \le
\|A\|_2^2 \|z\|_2^2\\
=\|A\|_2^2\sum_i (x_i^Ty_i)^2
\le \|A\|_2^2\sum_i \|x_i\|_2^2\|y_i\|_2^2\\
\le c^2\|A\|_2^2\sum_i \|x_i\|_2^2
= c^2\|A\|_2^2\|A\|_F^2\\
\le c^2d\|A\|_2^4 =  c^2d\|AA^T\|_2^2 = c^2d||\sum_{i=1}^k x_ix_i^T||_2^2.
$$
I used only the submultiplicative property of the norm for vectors and matrices, the fact that $d\|M\|^2_2\ge\|M\|_F^2$ and $\|M\|_2^2=\|MM^T\|_2$.

Comment: @learner write a new post with the new question

Comment: OK, Thanks very much! I will do that, looking forward to your answer! You are so excellent! @Exodd

Comment: I have written a new post. Could you please help me with that? Thanks a lot!